# Switch Control inside Settings->Genral->Accessibility iOS 7

Tags: ios, accessibility, uiaccessibility, switchcontrol

I am working with a application which has a blue tooth Switch attached to it. With the new iOS 7 Switch Control API I need to check if the iOS 7 Switch Control API is On or not. Is there any API provided to check if the Switch Control is on in the setting ?

Comment: Please, mark an answer as accepted to let people know that your problem has a solution... iOS 7 is far away now and Justin's answer should do the job. Terima kasih banyak. ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `UIAccessibilityIsSwitchControlRunning()` has been available since iOS 8. This API did not exist when your question was first posted.

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 8, you can use [UIAccessibilityIsSwitchControlRunning()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/1615131-uiaccessibilityisswitchcontrolru)

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5.0, besides the `UIAccessibility.isSwitchControlRunning` state provided by Justin's answer, you can listen to the **UIAccessibility.switchControlStatusDidChangeNotification** event to be aware of the [switch control status modification](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options).